# "Unable to get VPN permissions, you may need to reboot device and try again"

Tags: vpn, security, permissions, malware

On my Play Store-included Chinese Android phone (Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC), I recently encountered an issue where I had to re-accept permissions for all of my apps.  My VPN app failed, and I began getting errors that the phone itself was preventing me from connecting to a VPN.  I tried clearing the cache, the files, re-installing the app, using new VPN client and configuration files, restarting the phone, etc.  None of this helped.

Answer (score 2):

I backed up all of my data and reset the phone to factory defaults.

### Important reminder:

Before resetting the phone, I removed my MicroSD because the dialog said that it would delete everything on the MicroSD if I did not do this.

### Sussing out the source of the problem:

After reformatting my phone, I slowly installed each app that I thought might be the culprit.  Then, I slowly did each system app update.  I found there were a few apps that could cause the problem.  These are the apps that I suspect have the ability to permanently block connection to VPN in order of confidence with first being most certain: Mi Credit, Screenshot (by Mi), Updater (by Mi), and Security (by Mi).  There may be other system apps that create this problem.

Update: Themes (MI) also creates this problem, consistently.  The VPN connects and says that it is connected, but download rates drop to 0kbps.  If I remove myself from the MI Themes privacy policy and wait a few minuets, the VPN starts working again.  If I re-accept the privacy policy, the VPN stops working, again.  This is reproduceable.

### Methodology:

After reformatting, I spent a few hours connected to my VPN and browsing before installing any of these apps.  After installing them one-by-one, I encountered issues.  Removing updates did not undo the problem of the VPNs being blocked: I had to factory reset the phone, again.  I installed these other apps, one after each reset, to test each one of them.  I installed "updater" and "security" at the same time so it might be only one of these two, but I suspect that all of the system apps on the new MIUI system app update set are tainted.  Finally, I reset the device, ignored all updates, *turned off auto-update in three locations--Developer Options, System Apps Update settings, and System Apps Updater settings*--, and began to use my phone again.  Everything has been working fine for 24 hours.  If it fails hereafter, I will update my answer and include it as part of the question; so, if my answer is here, the theory stands.

### How is this happening?

If anyone knows why these apps are causing this problem or can guide me through figuring it out, please mention me in a comment.  Thank you!